# suddenly I get the error: Cannot find method setMimeType((class)) without any change

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

Suddenly my script get the error:

> Cannot find method setMimeType((class)) (line xxx, file "Code")

It worked well for years, until this afternoon. I didn't modified it at all.

What I've done after:

1. copied this code from [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content):

   ```
   function doGet() {
     var feed =  UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://xkcd.com/rss.xml').getContentText();
     feed = feed.replace(
       /(&lt;img.*?alt="(.*?)".*?&gt;)/g,
       '$1' + new Array(10).join('&lt;br /&gt;') + '$2');
     return ContentService.createTextOutput(feed)
       .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);
   }
   ```
2. pasted it into a new script
3. given it the proper authorizations
4. run it

It was ok.

Then:

5. renamed the doGet() function into doGet1() in my broken script
6. pasted the example doGet() function code
7. run my script (doGet function)

I obtained the same error:

> Cannot find method setMimeType((class)) (line xxx, file "Code")

What could have happened?

Comment: Is it only happening to that one specific script? I tried reproducing the behavior, it may be worth a shot to report it in the [IssueTracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) if you believe that it's a bug and not a code issue.

Comment: About `run it` and `run my script (doGet function)`, how do you run your script?

Comment: @Tanaike: I run the function from the toolbar.

Comment: We are receiving the same error on a script that ran for years. We started a Google Workspace case and reported it on the issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228222115

Comment: @Jason, please read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to debug my script, a message informed me that my project uses an old Apps Script runtime, and that in order to execute debug I have to upgrade to Javascript V8 engine. After doing that, everything went back to normal.
I attach a screenshot (from a different script, in Italian language).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

i just had the same error. my script stopped working.
it looks like the "ContentService.MimeType.RSS" does no longer exist.
"RSS" is no longer an autocomplete option if you type that.

i changed it to the "ContentService.MimeType.TEXT".
it is the closest option.
i also had to make a new deployment after saving the new code.

now my script is working again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is correct. I used the XML type and changed it to TEXT and it worked again.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.  The problem was that it is not possible to invoke .setMimeType() method, whatever MimeTYpe is.

Comment: Thanks. This answer helped me. My apps script suddenly stopped working due to this. Upgraded to v8, changed the mime type to ContentService.MimeType.TEXT, and fixed some other API changes in the v8 version of app script and got it working again.